# Why does this reach main() yet jQuery is still undefined?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, greasemonkey, preloader, userscripts

I'm trying to modify the various loaders out there so multiple scripts can be handled before the main function is called.  This should load jQuery, then jQueryUI, and then call main() to actually start the userscript.  However, it does loop through, but when it gets to main(), I get a console error from Chrome about jQuery being undefined.

```
!function loader (i) {
        var requires = [ 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'
                       , 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js'
                       ];
        var loadScript = function (i) {
                    var script    = document.createElement('script');
                    script.type   = 'text/javascript';
                    script.src    = requires[i];
                    script.onload = (++i === requires.length) ? function () { loader(i); }
                                                              : function () { main(); }
                    document.head.appendChild(script);
            };

        loadScript(i || 0);
}();

function main () {
    console.log(jQuery.version);
    console.log(jQuery.ui.version);
}
```

Comment: what's this `!function` all about?

Comment: Same as (function {})();

Comment: Why did you ignore the error about `document.appendChild(script);` not being valid operation?

Comment: Sorry - looks like that got dropped in my copy/pasting somehow.  /me edits :P

Comment: if you look at the dom with firebug or the inspector do you see the script elements that you expected to see? Also is it really better to load the js files one at a time rather than letting the browser sort out that stuff for you?

Comment: Pilate in ##javascript figured out the problem... the ternary logic was wrong.  It should have been:

    script.onload = (++i !== requires.length) ? function () { loader(i); }
                                              : function () { main(); }

Comment: ianbarker: in a userscript context, and with jQueryUI (and any jQuery plugins you might want) dependant on jQuery, you have no other choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the final script I came up with, if anyone's looking for this type of thing.
http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/123588

Pilate caught part of it, with the ternary.  Nate B also had part of it, with jQuery using jQuery.fn.jquery (but UI being inconsistent and using jQuery.ui.version).

It'd have been nice to figure out how to skip the wrapper bit in the middle, for 3rd party, but this works.  :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think `jQuery.version` is a valid property, and it returns `undefined`. Try `$.fn.jquery` in there instead and see what happens.

Comment: True but that wouldn't cause a `ReferenceError`